# How can I extract shared Scala enum logic into a trait or superclass?

Tags: scala, enums

I need to define a bunch of similar enums:

```
object Color extends MyEnum[Color.Color] {
  type Color = Value
  val Red, Green, Periwinkle = Value
}

object Shape extends MyEnum[Shape.Shape] {
  type Shape = Value
  val Square, Circle, Balbis = Value
}
```

I'd like to extract shared functionality into an abstract class or trait, to support 1) `apply` and `unapply` methods, and 2) implicit conversions from enums to their string representations:

```
abstract class MyEnum[T] extends Enumeration {
  implicit def valueToString(value: T): String = value.toString
  implicit def stringToValue(string: String): T = apply(string)

  def unapply(arg: String): Option[T] =
    values.find(_.toString == arg).map(_.asInstanceOf[T])

  def apply(arg: String): T =
    values.find(_.toString == arg)
      .getOrElse(sys.error(s"Invalid value '$arg'"))
      .asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

This doesn't compile; when I add the type param in `MyEnum[Color.Color]`, it breaks the `Value` type for some reason.

Is there some way to get what I want with this enum syntax, or do I need to switch to a case object solution (or something more complicated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Blog discusses the *Enumeration Hell* in Scala: [scala-enumerations-hell](https://medium.com/@yuriigorbylov/scala-enumerations-hell-5bdba2c1216)

The solution is not to use Scala's Enumeration type but create your own Enumeration class. Here is the abstract class from that blog:

```
abstract class Enum[Enum : ClassTag] { self =>
  val values = {
    import runtime.universe._
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(self.getClass.getClassLoader)
    val classSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(self.getClass)

    classSymbol.toType.members
      .filter(_.isModule)
      .map(symbol => mirror.reflectModule(symbol.asModule).instance)
      .collect { case v: Enum => v }
  }

  def forName(name: String): Option[Enum] = values.find(_.name == name)

  implicit class RichardEnum(enum: Enum) {
    def name: String = enum.toString
  }
}
```

There is also a framework that provides that for you: [lloydmeta/enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)